# How to fix this JsonMappingException: N/A during XML deserialization

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, jaxb, jackson

Here are my bean classes:

```
package request;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class Employee {



        private List<String> roles= new ArrayList<String>();


        private String name;


        public Employee(){}

        @JacksonXmlProperty
        public String getName ()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName (String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
        @JacksonXmlProperty
        public List<String> getRoles ()
        {
            return roleCodes;
        }

        public void setRoles (String role)
        {
            this.roles.add(role);
        }

        }
```

and,

```
package request;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;


public class Employees
{

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="employees")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="employee")
private ArrayList<Employee> emps;
//Employee Employee ;

public Employees(){}

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="employee")
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees ()
{

    return emps;
}
public void setEmployees(Employee emp){

    this.emps.add(emp);
}



@Override
public String toString()
{
    if(emps.isEmpty()!=true)
    for (Employee e:emps)
        return "this is  [employee = "+e ;
    return "none there";
}


public ArrayList<Employee> addingEmployee(Employee e){
    this.emps.add(e);
    return emps;
}
}
```

And here is the code to parse the xml into POJO:

```
package testPkg4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import request.Bean;
import request.Employee;
import request.Employees;

public class Test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        //Bean value = new Bean();

        Employees emps=new Employees();


        try {
            emps = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("D:\\workspace\\test\\src\\test\\resources\\employee.xml"),
                    Employees.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
       System.out.println(emps.getEmployees().get(0).getFirstName());
       //System.out.println(e.getFirstName());
       //System.out.println(emps.getEmployees().get(0).getThirdElement());
    }


    }
```

Now here is the error I am getting :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A  at [Source:
>   D:\workspace\test\src\test\resources\employee.xml; line: 5, column:
>   12] (through reference chain: request.Employees["employee"])  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:277)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:551)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:532)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:108)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2756)
>     at testPkg4.Test4.main(Test4.java:23) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   request.Employees.setEmployees(Employees.java:31)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:106)
>     ... 5 more Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at testPkg4.Test4.main(Test4.java:29)

while i am parsing thsi xml file:

```
<employees>
<employee>
<name>ASHISH</name>
<roles>MD</roles>
</employee>
<employee>
<name>BAHADUR</name>
<roles>CO</roles>
<roles>TM</roles>
</employee>
</employees>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Found an useful tutorial to create custom untyped xml deserializer  which helped me overcome it .
and in case of serialization create java classes from schema using jaxb2-maven-pluging as a build plug in .

> org.codehaus.mojo
>   jaxb2-maven-plugin
>   1.5
>   
>   
>   
>   xjc
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   -extension -npa -b ${project.basedir}/src/main/xsd/global.xjb

** if you are using jackson library then either replace the annotations with the jackson alternatives for jaxb annotaions . or register the jaxbannotation module into your serializer .

Here is the link for the [gist](https://gist.github.com/joaovarandas/1543e792ed6204f0cf5fe860cb7d58ed) that helped me .